# How do I access a static method of an non static object given just the string name of the object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that contains a static method.
Given only the name of this class as a 'string', how can I access the static method?

I know the string name is exactly the name of the class and I just want to do "nameofClass".methodIwantToxecute()

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: additional info...
I'm not able to write the exact class as code before I know the string name.  I'm reading the names of the class objects from a configuration file.

Comment: Reflection...coupled with expression trees or direct IL generation if performance is a concern.

Comment: Do you also know the name of the method you need to call?

Comment: Do you also know the namespace/assembly of the class?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes I know the method and expect it to be there

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple with reflection.

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "yourClass");
    type.GetMethod("Run", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: @erotavlas Deleted comment code would not work, you can go with this updated solution, though class name would require a namespace added to it, I presume

Comment: What if I want types not from the Executing assembly, but from a referenced assembly?

Comment: @erotavlas you can use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourType))` method if you know that a `YourType` resides in that assembly